# Lookup Master Detail Update scenario

Tags: lookup, master-detail, configuration

Object A's Id is there in Object B as lookup. B has a detail object in C.
Now when there is an update in A, C also fires the triggers in it for after insert, after update.

How is that possible? Can someone let me know?

Comment: Do you have a Roll-up of some sort?

Comment: Roll up update the master when records created on child.... Here the situation is reverse. So I am puzzled.

Comment: You must have some trigger logic on Object A which triggers update of C